# Error when deploying Django app on Heroku

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, heroku

I am trying to deploy new code at Heroku. The changes I made are simple, no changes to settings or requirements or anything fundamental.

However, when running git push, I get...

```
=====> Downloading Buildpack: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python.git
=====> Detected Framework: Python
-----> Installing requirements with pip
       ImportError: No module named site
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app.
!     Push failed
```

Does anybody have a clue what may be going on here?
I found similar questions already posted, but no clear answer and the proposed solutions didn't work in this case.

Heroku support suggested so far:

```
$ heroku config:unset PYTHONPATH
$ heroku config:unset PYTHONHOME
```

Following this, the deployment was possible, but the application stopped working.
By adding those variables back, the application was online again, but deployment would again fail.

Looking for a Solution for two days now -  I would appreciate any advice.

requirements.txt file is [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p8o0aq9jdx66w7q/requirements.txt).

Comment: Did you try `heroku buildpacks:clear` then `heroku buildpacks:add heroku/python`

Comment: I have a config var `BUILDPACK_URL` github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-multi.git. When running `heroku buildpacks:clear` I get _The BUILDPACK_URL config var is still set and will be used for the next release_ Removing the variable and executing the suggested steps did not fix the problem. I get the same error.

Comment: can you share your `requirements.txt` file?

Comment: Updated the question with the link to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the solution to the problem is to remove only the PYTHONHOME variable. The other variable is needed.

The reason was a change in heroku-buildpack-python.

More info here:
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python/issues/457